# ruby do statements if hash key satisfies condition

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have:

```
event = {"first_type_a" => 100, "first_type_b" => false, "second_type_a" => "abc", "second_type_b" => false}
```

I am trying to change the keys of `event` based on the original. If the name contains a substring, the name will be changed, and the new key, pair value should be added, and the old pair should be removed. I expect to get:

```
event = {"important.a_1" => 100, "important.b_1" => false, "second_type_a" => "abc", "second_type_b" => false}
```

What would be the most efficient way to update `event`?

I expected this to work:

```
event.each_pair { |k, v|
  if !!(/first_type_*/  =~ k) do
        key = "#{["important", k.split("_", 3)[2]].join(".")}";
        event.merge!(key: v);
        event.delete(k)  
  end
}
```

but it raises an error:

```
  simpleLoop.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
  ... if !!(/first_type_*/  =~ k) do
  ...                             ^~
  simpleLoop.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
    end
    ^~~
  simpleLoop.rb:21: embedded document meets end of file
```

I thought to approach it differently:

```
if result = event.keys.find { |k| k.include? "first_type_" } [
  key = "#{["important", k.split("_", 3)[2]].join(".")}"
  event.merge!(key: v)
  event.delete(k)
]
```

but still no luck. I am counting all brackets, and as the error indicates, it is something there, but I can't find it. Does the order matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just show how this can be done quite economically in Ruby. Until recently, when wanting to modify keys of a hash one usually would do one of two things:

- create a new empty hash and then add key/values pairs to the hash; or
- convert the hash to an array `a` of two-element arrays (key-value pairs), modify the first element of each element of `a` (the key) and then convert `a` to the desired hash.

Recently (with MRI v2.4) the Ruby monks bestowed on us the handy methods [Hash#transform_keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) and [Hash#transform_keys!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21). We can use the first of these profitably here. First we need a regular expression to match keys.

```
r = /
    \A           # match beginning of string
    first_type_  # match string
    (\p{Lower}+) # match 1+ lowercase letters in capture group 1
    \z           # match the end of the string
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Conventionally, this is written

```
r = /\Afirst_type_(\p{Lower}+)\z/
```

The use of *free-spacing mode* makes the regex self-documenting. We now apply the `transform_keys` method, together with the method [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-sub) and the regex just defined.

```
event = {"first_type_a"=>100, "first_type_b"=>false,
         "second_type_a"=>"abc", "second_type_b"=>false}

event.transform_keys { |k| k.sub(r, "important.#{'\1'}_1") }
  #=> {"important.a_1"=>100, "important.b_1"=>false,
  #    "second_type_a"=>"abc", "second_type_b"=>false}
```

In the regex the *p{} construct* expression `\p{Lower}` could be replaced with `\p{L}`, the *POSIX bracket expression* `[[:lower:]]` (both match Unicode letters) or `[a-z]`, but the last has the disadvantage that it will not match letters with diacritical marks. That includes letters of words borrowed from other languages that are used in English text (such as rosé, the wine). Search [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) for documentation of POSIX and `\p{}` expressions.

If `"first_type_"` could be followed by lowercase or uppercase letters use `\p{Alpha}`; if it could be followed by alphanumeric characters, use `\p{Alnum}`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` starts a block, such as other structures `if ... else ... end` `do ... end` `begin ... rescue ... end`

Therefore your first example remove the `do` after the `if`, the block is already open. I also made it clearer by changing the block after `each_pair` to use `do ... end` rather than braces to help avoid confusing a hash with a block.

```
event = { 'first_type_a' => 100, 'first_type_b' => false, 'second_type_a' => 'abc', 'second_type_b' => false }
new_event = {}
event.each_pair do |k, v|
  if !!(/first_type_*/  =~ k)
    important_key = ['important', k.split('_', 3)[2]].join('.')
    new_event[important_key] = v
  else
    new_event[k] = v
  end
end
```

Comment: I still have an error, this time `merge!': can't add a new key into hash during iteration (RuntimeError)` somehow can't make it work :(

Comment: You can't change the thing you are iterating on inside a loop. Make a 2nd variable to collect the different events.
I'll edit my answer. If you're just learning, try writing the program without mutating any variables, always assign a new variable. It's a functional programming trick to reduce confusing statefullness.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method to be used inside the transform key call:

```
def transform(str)
  return ['important.', str.split('_').last, '_1'].join() if str[0..4] == 'first' # I checked just for "first"
  str
end

event.transform_keys! { |k| transform(k) } # Ruby >= 2.5 
event.map { |k, v| [transform(k), v] }.to_h # Ruby < 2.5
```

Using [`Hash#each_pair`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-each_pair) but with [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
event.each_pair.with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[transform(k)] = v }
```

**Or use as one liner:**

```
event.transform_keys { |str| str[0..4] == 'first' ? ['important.', str.split('_').last, '_1'].join() : str  }
```